# How to equally reduce value after grouping?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have table in which some values belong to index and some other belong to  repeated values. In example `sid` is index, costs beolng to sid, but one sid can contain many transactions and even more one transaction can contain many categories.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 100, 1, 'A', 1, 50, 2],
    [1, 100, 2, 'A', 1, 50, 1],
    [1, 100, 2, 'B', 2, 100, 1],
    [1, 100, 2, 'C', 3, 50, 1],
    [2, 200, 3, 'D', 4, 500, 1],
    [2, 200, 4, 'C', 2, 100, 1],
    [3, 200, 5, 'B', 2, 100, 1],
    [3, 200, 5, 'A', 1, 50, 1],
    [3, 200, 5, 'A', 3, 50, 1]
], columns=['sid', 'costs', 'transaction_id', 'category', 'sku', 'price', 'quantity'])

df['revenue'] = df['price'] * df['quantity']
```

So if look on sid level I need to take first value of costs and sum of revenue. This is how it should looks like. Total costs - 500, total revenue - 1100.

```
df.groupby('sid').agg({'costs': 'min', 'revenue':'sum'}).pivot_table(index='sid', margins=True, aggfunc='sum')
```

[image]

But I want to decompose sid by category. I can do it this way.

```
df.groupby(['sid', 'category']).agg({'costs': 'min', 'revenue':'sum'}).pivot_table(index=['sid', 'category'], aggfunc='sum', margins=True)
```

[image]

My problem is that for every row costs were duplicated. And sum of costs is 1100 which is not true. I want to equally reduce costs regarding to amount of categories in each sid. So it will looks like

[image]

Is it possible to apply such rolling function?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. How are you getting costs of 33.34 for sid 1 and category A?

Comment: @amanbirs this is example of what I want to achieve. Yes, I understand that this probably doesn't have sens in terms of costs, because this is not that value that was spent on certain category, but now I'm interested in achieving such result with pandas. How to interpret it is another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need divide count of `sid` per groups created by [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['sid', 'category']).agg({'costs': 'min', 'revenue':'sum'})
df['costs'] = df['costs'].div(df.groupby('sid')['costs'].transform('size'))
df = df.pivot_table(index=['sid', 'category'], aggfunc='sum', margins=True)
print (df)
                   costs  revenue
sid category                     
1   A          33.333333      150
    B          33.333333      100
    C          33.333333       50
2   C         100.000000      100
    D         100.000000      500
3   A         100.000000      100
    B         100.000000      100
All           500.000000     1100
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's something you could do:

```
g = df.groupby(['sid', 'category']).agg({'revenue':'sum', 'costs': 'min'})
div = df.groupby(['sid'])['category'].nunique()
g['costs'] = g['costs']/div

                revenue     costs
sid category                     
1   A             150   33.333333
    B             100   33.333333
    C              50   33.333333
2   C             100  100.000000
    D             500  100.000000
3   A             100  100.000000
    B             100  100.000000
```

And for the last row, including the `sum` of the two columns simply add again at the end:

```
g.pivot_table(index=['sid', 'category'], aggfunc='sum', margins=True)
```